# Is it possible to start a character with tremorsense? What kind of negative stats would I need to take?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

I'm starting a campaign and I think it'd be cool if I could be a human and have tremorsense. I know it'd be hard, but I'd be willing to take a lot of negative stats to counteract that. If it'd be hard to start with it, how could I get trained in it?

Comment: Hi Scar and welcome to the site. Could you please explain which edition of D&D are you going to play? You can label the question with the appropriate tag ([tag:dnd-3.5e], [tag:dnd-4e], [tag:pathfinder] and so on)

Comment: This is closed till you clarify what edition of D&D you're talking about... It can be reopened once you clarify.  The answer is significantly different per edition.

Answer (score 10):

Noting that [Tremorsense](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD%3aTremorsense) is an [Extrodinary ability](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD%3aEx#Extraordinary), at least in the 3.5 SRD, and starting with the following two discussions, [Tremorsense???](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=128249) and [Ways to Get Tremorsense?](http://www.enworld.org/forum/d-d-legacy-discussion/210023-ways-get-tremorsense.html), we find the following possibilities:

- Take a template:

  - [Insectile Template (Inherited)](http://kahdnd.pbworks.com/w/page/34340844/Insectile%20Creature) (or [[Savage Species p.121-22]](http://www.roleplaynexus.com/creaturetemplates.html))

    > within 60 feet
  - [Element-Infused Creature (earth)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/element-infused-creature)

    > within 20 feet
- Take an alternate class:

  - [Elementalist (earth)](http://dungeons.wikia.com/wiki/Elementalist_%283.5e_Class%29)

    > 30 foot Tremor Sense
  - [Horizon Walker Cavernous (Planar)](http://www.angelfire.com/pro/demon_1/prc_horizon_walker.htm)

    > You gain tremor sense with a 30-foot range.
- Use a magic item:

  - [Antennae Graft](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=12154.0) Fiend Follio (p212)

    > Range of 60ft, and only 20,000gp
  - [Boots of Tremorsense](http://www.imarvintpa.com/dndlive/items.php?ID=4975)

    > Sense any creature or object within 30' in contact with ground

Although not as powerful, you could instead:

- Use the spell:

  - [Tremorsense](http://dndtools.eu/spells/underdark--34/tremorsense--3521/)

> You can automatically pinpoint the location of any object or creature within 30 feet that is in contact with the ground.

Take a feat:

- [Earth Sense](http://dndtools.eu/feats/races-of-stone--82/earth-sense--797/)

  > touching the ground, you can take a move action to sense the number of creatures within 20 feet that are also touching the ground and the direction to each one. You cannot pinpoint the location of any creature with this feat.
- [Scorpion's Sense](http://dndtools.eu/feats/sandstorm--85/scorpions-sense--2527/)

  > automatically pinpoint the location of anything that is moving and in contact with the ground so long as it is within 10 feet. The range expands to 20 feet if you are in an area covered in a layer of at least 1 inch of ash, dust, loose earth, or sand. This ability only tells you what square the creature is in, so you still have the normal miss chance from concealment if you cannot see the creature.

Benefit from an alternative:

- [Play a monster race](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monstersAsRaces.htm) with Tremorsense
- [Blindsight and Blindsense](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD%3aBlindsight_and_Blindsense)

Comment: This answer would be better if it answered the question about a *starting* character with tremorsense - a lot of these are clearly higher-level-only techniques.

Comment: @mxyzplk Upon reflection the classes do require a higher level than the OP appears to be looking for.  Is it acceptable on rpg.se to effectively answer the question with "do not do that because..."?  I know that other se sites have that policy, and if a similar policy exists here then I hope this answer will stand, if it does not then please edit out the inapplicable parts, or if an edit would leave no effective content remove it entirely.

Comment: Feel free and edit  your own post, I'm just saying you are at risk of downvote for not accurately answering the question posed.

Comment: Given that many campaigns start at a level higher than 1, I don't immediately interpret "start a character" as "build a level 1 character".